# Accelerated gradient descent versus nonlinear conjugate gradient descent

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Let's consider smooth and convex minimization problem, i.e. $min f(x)$, where $f$ is not necessarily a quadratic function. If measured by iterations,

1. Accelerated Gradient Descend (AGD) has $O(1/T^2)$ rate for weak convex case and linear rate with strong convexity.
2. Nonlinear Conjugate Gradient descent (Nonlinear-CGD) has not explicit rate (I got this from Section 5.2 at [Numerical Optimization](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-0-387-40065-5)).

But, in quadratic case CGD works much better than APG, i.e. much less iterations are needed to achieve desired precision.

Therefore, is it the same when apply APG and Nonlinear-CGD on above $min f(x)$?

Comment: Besides, what's the dependency of Nonlinear-CGD on conditional number (c)?  I know it is sqrt(c) for APG, then how about Nonlinear-CGD?

Comment: I've done a detailed comparison on this task. I use matrix completion problem as testing seedbed.  In a word, for general case, though AGD works better, there is no absolute win between them. For me, I prefer trying AGD first, since it is simpler to implement and can handle other constrains more easily. Code and PDF: https://github.com/quanmingyao/NCG-vs-AGD.